# How to workaround limitation for Iceberg Tables not accessible from Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum, apache-iceberg

I have different Iceberg tables built and updated using Python scripts on Glue. I need now to access to them via Redshift Spectrum. From documentation (and some personal tests) it seems not possible doing that. Is there any workaround for it (apart from re-writing everything with Spark/Hudi/DeltaLake)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just asked 3 months ago you are so lucky, AWS Redshift now support Iceberg: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/amazon-redshift-querying-apache-iceberg-tables/

Comment: ah! great news thank you! I also opened a request with AWS team at the time  and meanwhile I had to implement a dreadful workaround (that I can now remove) rotating location pointing to the tables in a S3 folder with 30 days expire for an Athena copy table